# How to add text input nodes in Network - Chaps link library

Tags: javascript, visualization, chap-links-library

Here i'm trying out with one of the [example](http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/network/examples/example03_images.html) mentioned in `Network- Chaps link library`. In this example they are appending images to nodes. Like wise, is there a way to append text input into nodes?

Please suggest a method.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean exactly with "appending text input". Do you mean having an HTML text input field?

Comment: Yes that's right, i want to append HTML input field to nodes.

Comment: That's not possible, as the Network visualization uses HTML Canvas.

Comment: Can you please explain why it can't append an input field, if it can append an image into node?

Comment: Check out some tutorials on what HTML canvas is and how it works. HTML canvas basically gives you an area where you can draw pixels. It supports things like drawing lines, rects, arcs, text, and images. But it is not interactive and you can't put HTML in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use any HTML in the network visualization itself as the visualization uses HTML canvas.

The only thing you could do is provide a title to your nodes. This title is displayed when the user hovers over the node. The title can contain HTML code including input fields.